# Pdf is not get attached to my email

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, phpmailer, codeigniter-3

I have written a function to send email with attachment.i used PHPMailer class.
Email is send,but the attachment is not getting.

My Controller Code

```
public function send_mail() 
      {
        $this->load->library('email');

            $subject = 'Request For Quotation';
            $message = '<p>This message has been sent for testing purposes.</p>';

            // Get full html:
            $body =
'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset='.strtolower(config_item('charset')).'" />
    <title>'.html_escape($subject).'</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
'.$message.'
</body>
//</html>';
            $this->load->library('M_pdf');
   $this->m_pdf->pdf->setTitle('Request for Quotation');
   $html = 'hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii';
   $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);
   $content=$this->m_pdf->pdf->Output('RFQ.pdf',"S");
   $result = $this->email->from('mm@jiklink.com')->to('jk@gmail.com')->subject($subject)->message($body)->attach($content, '', 'base64', '')->send();
   var_dump($result); // echo '<br />'; echo $this->email->print_debugger(); exit;
    }
```

Comment: Reaping the rewards of pointless fluent interfaces. Add some exception handling and/or check your return values.

Comment: can u help me,i tried a lot,but not getting

Comment: You need to [read the codeigniter docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html).

Comment: i used PHPMailer with codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

```
   use this code.............. 
   $pdfFilePath = "PDF/RFQ.pdf";
    $html='hiiiiiiiiiiiiiii';
    //load mPDF library
    $this->load->library('m_pdf');
    //generate the PDF from the given html
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);
    //download it.
    ob_clean(); 
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath,'F');


    $config = Array(
      'protocol' => 'smtp',
      'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
      'smtp_port' => 465,
      'smtp_user' => 'Email', 
      'smtp_pass' => 'Password', 
      'mailtype' => 'html',
      'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
      'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );
      $this->load->helper('path');
      $this->load->library('email', $config);
      $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
      $this->email->from('Email');
      $this->email->to('email');
      $this->email->subject('Subject');
      $this->email->attach($pdfFilePath);
      $this->email->send();
```